# Which is faster for removing items from a List<object> - RemoveAll or a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, .net

For removing an object where a property equals a value which is faster?

```
foreach(object o in objects)
{
    if(o.name == "John Smith")
    {
         objects.Remove(o);
         break;
    }
}
```

or

```
objects.RemoveAll(o => o.Name == "John Smith");
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

I should have mentioned this is removing one object from the collection, then breaking out of the loop which prevents any errors you have described, although using a for loop with the count is the better option!

Comment: The first one will give you an exception about modifying the collection while iterating over it...  Realistically, a modification of the first approach (maintaining a separate collection, then removing the items in the second collection from the first) is probably what the second option does behind the scenes.

Comment: The foreach loop works when your only looking to remove one object (say with a given id) from the collection, once you have removed the object, your break out of the loop which prevents an exception being thrown. I agree a for loop is the better option though - thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: In that case, the behavior is different between the two - one removes a single element, the other removes all elements that match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a `List<string>` of 10,000 items, the speeds are:

- for loop: 110,000 ticks
- lambda: 1,000 ticks

From this information, we can conclude that the lambda expression is faster.

The source code I used can be found [here](http://pastebin.com).

Note that I substituted your `foreach` with a `for` loop, since we aren't able to modify values within a `foreach` loop.

Comment: You may want to fix up that link. It points to the top level URL and I'm sure we don't want to play "Hunt the wumpus" to find your actual code :-)

Comment: Also you should try RemoveAt, seeing as Remove is essentially RemoteAt(IndexOf(o)). Which will be a lot slower.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly the answer I was after - despite my rubbish example!

Answer (score 16):

If you really want to know if one thing is faster than another, benchmark it. In other words, *measure, don't guess!* This is probably my favorite mantra.

As well as the fact that you're breaking the rules in the first one (modifying the list during the processing of it, leading me to invoke my second mantra: *You can't get any more unoptimised than "wrong"*), the second is more readable and *that's* usually what I aim for first.

And, just to complete my unholy trinity of mantras: *Optimise for readability first, then optimise for speed only where necessary* :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
{
    if(objects[i].name == "John Smith")
    {
         objects.Remove(objects[i--]);
    }
}
```

RemoveAll would be faster in this case. As with Remove you are iterating over the list again(IndexOf) when you already have the position.

Here is List.Remove

```
public bool Remove(T item)
{
    int index = this.IndexOf(item);
    if (index >= 0x0)
    {
        this.RemoveAt(index);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```